# Does 7z compression affected by CPU efficiency

Tags: cpu, compression, 7-zip

I'm currently archiving a huge amount of data to 7zip, but i've a question regarding the result:

Given two processors: 1 very powerfull and the second low-cost
-or-
Given the same processor but 1 time idle and the second time very busy

Which situation is the right one:

A) The result will be the same (same ratio) but the time needed by the slowest is more important.

B) The result will not be the same, it does not depend on the time needed: A powerfull or idle CPU will have a better compression ratio than the low-cost or busy one.

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7zip uses repeatable algorithms. This implies, that the result is not dependent on the CPU model or load. The time to process of course will depend.

So your answer A) is correct.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer !